# put haml tags inside link_to helper

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, haml

is it possible to add html-content inside a link_to helper in HAML?

i tried this, but all i get is a syntax error:

```
= link_to "Other page", "path/to/page.html"
    %span.icon Arrow
```

expected output:

```
<a href="path/to/page.html">Other Page<span class="icon">Arrow</span></a>
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You should use block

```
= link_to "path/to/page.html" do
  Other page
  %span.icon Arrow
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get rid of the extra space that's being created by that code at the end of the link?  It's noticeable when I hover over it when the entire link becomes underlined.

Comment: Thank you this is very useful. You missed to explain that it's important to note that when using `do` block in `link_to`, the only parameter is the path, and the text of the link, or any other content goes within the block.

Comment: If you use the [font-awesome-sass gem](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass#a-ruby-on-rails), you can also use e.g. `= icon "arrow-right"` instead of `%span.icon Arrow` that invokes the helper method.

Answer (score 12):

If anyone is still using Rails 2.x on a project, it looks like the accepted answer returns the block, thus duplicating the link in the markup. Very simple change: use `-` instead of `=`

```
- link_to "path/to/page.html" do
  Other page
  %span.icon Arrow
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do it is by using html_safe or raw functions

```
= link_to 'Other Page<span class="icon"></span>'.html_safe, "path/to/page.html"
```

or using raw function (recommended)

```
= link_to raw('Other Page<span class="icon"></span>'), "path/to/page.html"
```

Simple as it can get !!

Don’t use html_safe method unless you’re sure your string isn’t nil. Instead use the raw() method, which wont raise an exception on nil.