# How to put %span inside of =link_to helper?

Tags: haml

```
= link_to t('actions.convert_to_template'), convert_backup_path(backup), {:title=> t('.convert_backup'), :class => 'icon convert_to_template'}  if backup.built? && authorized?(backup, :update)
```

How do I put %span t('actions.convert_to_template') inside of this link_to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a helper, like this

```
def convert_to_template_text
  html = content_tag :span, t('actions.convert_to_template')
  html.html_safe
end
```

or [use block with link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618971/put-haml-tags-inside-link-to-helper)