# Haml render different HTML in two different stages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a problem with my app.

Two stages, same app, same deploy recipes and of course same gems.

In my staging environment everything is ok, in my production environment the HTML is slightly different and this cause to me some rendering issue.

Example.

**Staging**

```
<a class="btn red" href="/admin/contents/new?type=News" title="News">News
<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>
</a>
<a class="btn blue" href="/admin/contents/new?type=Article" title="Article">Articolo
```

**Production**

```
<a class="btn red" href="/admin/contents/new?type=News" title="News">News
<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>
</a><a class="btn blue" href="/admin/contents/new?type=Article" title="Article">Articolo
```

The difference is small, but the problem is that in my production environment I lose all the space between buttons.

The code that generate this button is simple:

```
.col-md-3
  = link_to new_admin_content_path(type: 'News'), class: "btn red", title: "News" do
    News
    %i.fa.fa-plus
  = link_to new_admin_content_path(type: 'Article'), class: "btn blue", title: "Article" do
    Articolo
    %i.fa.fa-plus
```

What's the problem???

Comment: You need to include the correct Haml source – what you have there will give an error. Make sure the indentation is right.

Comment: Ya... the haml as written will not produce either of the HTML outputs you've shown us.  The indentation is wrong.

Comment: The 'do' in necessary.
[look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618971/put-haml-tags-inside-link-to-helper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from haml FAQ:

> Why is my markup indented properly in development mode, but not in production?
>
> To improve performance, Haml defaults to {Haml::Options#ugly "ugly" mode} in Rails apps running in production.

Link to [FAQ](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/7884fae7af29e6cf7b862b270501685ff39ce137/FAQ.md) itself. To fix this issue, you need to provide Haml with a different option. So, you basically need to implement an initializer with correct setting:

```
# config/initializers/haml.rb
Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = false
Haml::Template.options[:remove_whitespace] = false
```

Here's a [link to other examples](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/7884fae7af29e6cf7b862b270501685ff39ce137/REFERENCE.md#options).

List of available options can be found [here](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/1c29b4903855a10da386563138cce936ab109b0b/lib/haml/options.rb).

Comment: I edited the indentation.

HAML is working. The problem is the new line after </a> tag

Comment: Do you use spaces or tabs? Are you sure there's no intendation mixing in your file?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/robypez/8966677) is the gist... all spaces. By the way on my staging server everything is ok!!!

Comment: W00t?! The problem just fade away?

Comment: Have you read the question???? My problem is that the same HALM code is compiled in a different way on two different server.

Comment: I've just mixed up staging and production for a moment. I get your problem perfectly.

Comment: @RobertoPezzali I think this is actually a bug in Haml – you should be able to use ugly mode in production. I’ve opened an issue at https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/748.